# Can a method be added to the combine function to handle arguments of different classes?

Tags: r

I've made a new class, `cvb`:

```
setClass("cvb", slots = c(name = "character", dargs = "list"))
cvb <- function(name, ...) {
  out <- list(name = name, dargs = list(...))
  class(out) <- "cvb"
  out
}
```

And I'd like to be able to call a method to the "combine" function, `c(...)`, with arguments that are of class `cvb`, `numeric`, and `character`. I can make a method like so (not even needing to bother with S4 actually) if the first argument to `c(...)` is of class `cvb`:

```
c.cvb <- function(...) "In cbv c method"
```

which will return whatever "combination" of arguments my method defines. But I want to be able to deploy this method if *any* of the arguments are of class `cvb`, and use the default method otherwise. If the first argument to `c(...)` is not of class `cvb` I get the following:

```
> v <- cvb("i", 1:3)
> c(1, 2, v)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

$name
[1] "i"

$dargs
$dargs[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Which combines two `numeric` types and a `list` type into a list, even though the first argument isn't a list. This suggests to me that there is some kind of dispatch logic that determines that if any argument is a list argument, combine all arguments into a list. I'd like it to use my `c.cvb` method instead of whatever is being dispatched here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with S4 dispatch but am somewhat familiar with S3 dispatch. So there is likely a better way, but one option would be to supply your own dispatch logic by overriding `c()`:

```r
# cvb generator
cvb <- function(name, ...) {
  out <- list(name = name, dargs = list(...))
  class(out) <- "cvb"
  out
}

# instance of cvb
v <- cvb("i", 1:3)

# new S3 c method for cvb object
c.cvb <- function(...) "In cbv c method"

# dispatch to new S3 method gives desired output
c(v, 1, 2)
#> [1] "In cbv c method"

# but will only work if the first object is of class cvb 
c(1, 2, v)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $name
#> [1] "i"
#> 
#> $dargs
#> $dargs[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3

# S3 dispatch pre-hook
c <- function(...) {
  if("cvb" %in% unlist(lapply(list(...), class)))
    c.cvb(...)
  else
    base::c(...)
}

# now we get c.cvb if any argument has class cvb
c(1, 2, v)
#> [1] "In cbv c method"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>